# I am creating Post rest api but not working route in the postman showing error how can i solve the error ?? Only Get api working properly in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating Post rest API but not working route in the postman showing error how can i solve the error ?? Only Get API working properly in la-ravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4BL7.png)

Comment: Please show us the result of php artisan route:list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.